# How to enable database logging without modifying the core?

Tags: database, debug

I am afraid that this might be a rhetorical question, but:

Is there any other and cleaner way to enable DB logging then modifying the file `Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and set `$_debug` and `$_logAllQueries` to `true`?

Answer (score 2):

Just turn it on in my.cnf (usually in /etc/mysql at least it is on Ubuntu).

Use the following lines, restart mysql and it should be logging pretty much everything.

```
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the File to `local/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdy/Mysql.php` and modify it there.

OR you could extend this class and set it in the `local.xml`

`global/resources/default_setup/connection/type -> pdo_mysql_debug` and then implement a `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql_Debug` in `local/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdy/Mysql/Debug.php`